# Eigenvectors of an integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I need to find the spectrum of the following integral operator on $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$:
$Tf(t)=\int_{-\pi} ^{\pi} \frac 1{1-0.5 e^{i(t-s)}}f(s)ds$.

I know that this is a self-adjoint anc compact operator, so the spectrum is just the eigenvalues and $0$. I tried several techniques to find the eigenvalues, but none were successful. I know that in many of these problems I can get a second order differential equation. Is it possible here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e_k(t)=e^{ikt}$ and $\langle f,g\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \overline f(t)g(t)dt$, such that $\langle e_j,e_k\rangle=\delta_{jk}$.  Since $f(s)=\sum_{\mathbb Z}\hat {f_k} e_k(s)$, and $\frac{1}{1-0.5e^{i(t-s)}}=\sum_0^\infty 2^{-j}e_j(t)\overline{e_j(s)}$, we obtain
$$
Tf(t)=2\pi\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-j}e_j(t)\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat {f_k}\langle e_j,e_k\rangle=2\pi\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{-j}\hat{f_j}e_j(t).
$$
The eigenfunctions are thus $e_j$, with eigenvalues $2\pi/2^j$ if $j\ge 0$.  Note that $Te_j=0$ if $j<0$.

Note that the integral kernel of $T$ is translation invariant, so T commutes with the Laplacian $\Delta=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$.  This told me that $T$ and $\Delta$ could be simultaneously diagonalized.